# How to recover magento, when database is alive but ALL the files are removed?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, backup

So I have a Magento website where **ALL the files are removed** by accident and there is no back up for it.

But, the **database** is still alive and **working**.

Is there anyway for me to recover at least some parts of my website? Or at least my products and data? I am aware that my front-end and all its changes are removed, but is there an approach to at least get my products and data up and running again? Even if it's to use another template for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a good solid backup of the database and then duplicate it in MySQL.

Install the exact version of Magento that was installed along with any third party modules.

When you start Magento, it will ask for a database to connect to, give it the database and login credentials.

Troubleshoot out any issues you have for missing modules, database edit to switch it to one of Magento's default themes.

Moving forward, start backing up the database and application. It's pretty simple, all you need is a compressed tarball of the server's doc root and a compressed mysql dump. Create and copy off every so often and you'll be able to recover a lot easier from this sort of disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Products, Sales, and Customers are all actually stored in the database which should be all you really need if you are willing to use a new theme. You could install a fresh magento installation on to the database if you like. Clean the database of old modules/extensions tables and you should have all your old data (not files).